# enable onCollitionEnter by a variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 script and i am try to make one trigger for the first script to enable other script trigger, i have try to investigate but i still stuck on my code.

my first code is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class endpoint10 : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int IsColliderEnabled;
    endpoint10.IsColliderEnabled = 0;
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (IsColliderEnabled = 1) {
            //do stuff here
            // The switch statement checks what tag the other gameobject is,      and reacts accordingly.
            switch (other.gameObject.tag) {
            case "end":
                Debug.Log (other.gameObject.tag);

                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("moneyPref", scoreManager.money);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("scorePref", scoreManager.score);
                ScoreSystem.level += 1;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("levelPref", ScoreSystem.level);
                Debug.Log ("values stored");
                Application.LoadLevel ("level_11");
                break;

            }
        }
        // Finally, this line destroys the gameObject the player collided with.
        //Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

and my second code is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class trigguercubex : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] objects;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        endpoint10.IsColliderEnabled = 1;
        Debug.Log (other.gameObject.tag);



    }

        // Finally, this line destroys the gameObject the player collided with.
        //Destroy(other.gameObject);

}
```

Comment: You do realize that in your if statement, you're setting the value of IsColliderEnabled to 1 and not testing if it is equal to 1... right?

Comment: Yes finaly i have made some changes and use two more new variables and change them wen i need 0 to one i have tested the code withh no erros but i not tested yet the final results i will let all know the final of it. And No I not used the game manager i am a developer from other codes and i start with js and c# just a few weeks ago.

Comment: And It is that my difficult of it, i don know how to compare it , so i decide it to make 2 new public variables one for one one for off and play with it wen i need

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a game manager script?
You could use setters and getters

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public static GameManager instance = null;

private bool triggerredOccurred = false;

public bool IsTriggerredOccurred {
    get { return triggerredOccurred;}
}

public void TriggerredOccurred() {
    triggerredOccurred = true;
}

void Awake(){
    if (instance == null) { //check if an instance of Game Manager is created
        instance = this;    //if not create one
    } else if (instance != this) {
        Destroy(gameObject);    //if already exists destroy the new one trying to be created
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);  //Unity function allows a game object to persist between scenes
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    }
}
```

In your endpoint class, when the collision was detected

```
GameManager.instance.TriggerOccurred ();
```

In your trigguercubex class

```
if (GameManager.instance.IsTriggerOccurred) {
    do some stuff ();
}
```

I attach the GameManager script to my game's Main Camera

Comment: hi hello tank you for the help but its come an error  GameManager does not contain a definition for instance